# Raw partitioning software for Windows 10

Tags: windows, hard-disk, filesystems

Almost all partitioning software that I've seen does mandatory filesystem checking and data moving before actually changing the partition table. I'm looking for a software that does raw partitioning (i.e. only change partition table without doing anything else). In case I don't care about data or want precise partitioning, such a software is very useful compared to regular ones.

The software I am looking for

- Must be able to change partition table without moving data and checking filesystem consistency and the blah blah blah things that regular softwares do.
- Must support GPT (let's kick out `fdisk`).
- Must support moving and shrinking partitions.
- Must run on Windows 10 without requiring compatibility mode (i.e. natively compatible with Windows 10).
- Must be free or have a free version that does not expire. Advertisements are acceptable.

- Preferrably has a GUI, although a command-line program is OK.
- Preferrably has an "Operation Queue" (show operations "virtually", does not write anything before finally confirming all operations).
- Preferrably supports "legacy" operations (i.e. option to do a lot of stuff before finally writing partition table.

- Optionally is available for Linux.
- Optionally has both GUI and CLI.
- Optionally is able to recognize non-Windows filesystem types, e.g. HFS+ and ext4.
- Optionally is able to "force format" into a given filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

If I can't deal with partitions using built-in tools to the running OS ('cause you can't mess with mounted/in-use partitions, etc) I boot with a Linux Mint LiveDVD and run `parted` (command line) or `gparted` (GUI front end).  Hits all of your points except running in Windows (of any version), which I think would be moot due to the operating on filesystems that are in use bit... .

Comment: GParted is somehow buggy. It often shows that there are 8MiB free space between partitions, which does not exist on Windows. And the CLI parted doesn't seem to be able to move partitions. It can only change partition end position, but not start position.